# How to push outlook calendar online?

Tags: outlook, office365

How to push outlook calendar online?

My client is using Office 365. He is expecting to publish his daily meeting calendar online. Per his expectation, available date and time should be open and visible for any one to book his calendar. Any booked date / time will show as Not Available (or) Blocked.  Objective is not to show the detail of booked date / time.

Do we have a third party tool to do so ? Or , Office 365 supports this feature.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called "Free/Busy" and Office 365 supports it. You can search the Internet for "office 365 share free busy" and choose your option.